# how to change font color based off database result

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

In my report, I'd like to change the font color of a text box (text box contains a circle wingdings character, different colors will be used for different statuses). I have a field in my database that has one of 5 options - r,y,b,g, or o for red, yellow, blue, green or orange. Is there a way based on this result for the item to change the color of the textbox to match the corresponding color for each item in the report? Thank you, I am new to crystal reports.

Edit- I tried to right click on the text box where I have placed the circle and then went to formatting. I don't see the formula box like I do when I click on a DB field. Any way around this? I need the colored circle, not just a circle in every item and it needs to relate to that color from the DB field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes:

- Right-click on your text box and select Format Field... .
- Select the Font tab in the Format Editor dialog.
- Click on the `x-2` button to the right of the selected Color option (which will default to black).
- In the Format Formula Editor, enter a formula like:

```
if {myTable.ColourOption} = "r" then crRed else 
if {myTable.ColourOption} = "y" then crYellow else 
if {myTable.ColourOption} = "g" then crGreen else 
if {myTable.ColourOption} = "b" then crBlue else 
if {myTable.ColourOption} = "o" then Color (255, 128, 0)
```

The function pane of the Format Formula Editor should include a `Color Constants` node - this will list available predefined Crystal colours, or you can define your own using the `Color (r, g, b)` function.

- Click on the `x-2` check button (or press Alt and C) to check whether the entered formula is valid - if it is, click the Save and close button at the top left of the Format Formula Editor, then click on the OK button at the bottom of the Format Editor dialog.

If you now preview the report, you should find that your text box is coloured based on the value of your colour option field.

Comment: I don't have an x-2 button (only missing in font tab) when right clicking on the text object. Is there another way to get to this? Maybe I did not set up the text box right (clicked add text object - dropped to report - changed font to wingdings and typed l for the circle). Thanks

Comment: @njj56: Are you editing a report created in an earlier version of Crystal? I have CR 10 - reports created in CR 10 have the `x-2` button next to the Font tab Color option, but reports created in CR 8 do not have it available.

Comment: I am in CR 2011, created it from scratch last week in the same program.

Comment: You need to create a formula field with your text in then place that on the report. The x-2 button will be available for the formula field

Comment: @njj56: Actually, it is text boxes that don't have the Font tab Color option `x-2` button - the simplest workaround would be to add a new Formula field (defined as the string corresponding to the Wingdings circle character) and add it to the report in place of the text box, with the Font set to Wingdings and the Font Color set to the formula as described above.

Comment: If the text is going to be the character "l" in wingdings (to show a circle) - how would I do this? Sorry for all the easy questions, new to crystal reports

edit - basically how do I set the text in a formula field to always be the letter "l" - only way i can think is to make a new column in my DB and have every value = "l" - but there has to be another way

Comment: @njj56: Just enter the Formula as `"l"` in the formula editor.

Comment: Thanks, quotes - who would have though ;)

Answer (score 0):

not sure what version of crystal you are using, but all I had to do was:

Right click on the field I want to change color when a condition is met

Select the "Highlighting Expert"

Once in the Highlighting Expert, click the New button, and then select the condition and formatting you want for that condition

Hope this helps you.